# Cant find bug, EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exc-bad-access

Last time I posted on Stackowerflow I screwed up because thought I knew more than I did. Renamed methods to make it easier and just made everything very confusing. So I am going to make another try now.

Anyways, my application have been rejected a couple of times by Apple and I can´t find the bug. I have been running the simulator as well as AD-HOC install and can’t seem to find the bug or even replicate it.

I have no warnings and have been using static analyzer and can´t find any problems there either.

I am new to Objective C and think that I am doing something wrong with how I am using class methods but I am not sure.

It´s the last one, the class method ”itemStatus” that crashes.

Im am using ARC by the way.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
   Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
    Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x432b2b10
    Crashed Thread:  0

    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a3c3526 objc_retain + 6
    1   Kebunno                     0x0008928a +[DynamoDBManager itemStatus] + 418
    2   Kebunno                     0x000894de +[DynamoDBManager getItem:] + 170
    3   Kebunno                     0x000908f6 __44-[KebunnoViewController itemPressed]_block_invoke + 362
```

First class

```
@interface KebunnoViewController ()

// Interface declarations here

@end


@implementation KebunnoViewController

- (IBAction)itemPressed:(id)sender {
    NSString *itemID = _itemID.text;
    NSString *reference = _reference.text;


    BOOL itemCorrect = NO;
    if([ItemHelpClass validItem:itemID]){
    itemCorrect = YES;
    }

    if(!itemCorrect){
        [[ItemHelpClass showItemNotCorrect:self] show];
        return;
    }


    else if(itemCorrect){
        [self startCancelTimer];
        [self disableButtons];

        dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("background queue", NULL);
        dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
            NSString *itemStatus;
            itemStatus = [DynamoDBManager getItem:itemID]; //crash

         if([itemStatus isEqualToString:NETWORK_ERROR] || 
          [itemStatus  isEqualToString:AMAZON_ERROR]){
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self enableButtons];
                    [[ItemHelpClass showSomethingWentWrong:self] show];
                });
            }

//Code continues
}

@end
```

Another file called DynamoDBMangar.m

```
@implementation DynamoDBManager

+(NSString*)getItem:(NSString *)itemID {
    NetworkStatus netStatus = 
    [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection]currentReachabilityStatus];

    if(netStatus == NotReachable)
    {
        return NETWORK_ERROR;
    }

    NSString *itemStatus = [self itemStatus]; //crash
    if([itemStatus isEqualToString: ITEM_BORROWED]){
        return ITEM_BORROWED;
    }
    else if([itemStatus isEqualToString:NETWORK_ERROR])
    {
        return NETWORK_ERROR;
    }

//Code continues
}



+(NSString*) itemStatus{
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection]currentReachabilityStatus];
    if(netStatus == NotReachable)
    {
        return NETWORK_ERROR;
    }


    @try
    {

        DynamoDBGetItemRequest *request = [[DynamoDBGetItemRequest alloc] initWithTableName: TABLE_CONTENT andKey:[[DynamoDBKey alloc] initWithHashKeyElement:
                                                                   [[DynamoDBAttributeValue alloc] initWithS:[ItemHelpClass getItem]]]];

        DynamoDBGetItemResponse *response = [[AmazonClientManager ddb] getItem:request];
        if(response){
            if(((DynamoDBAttributeValue *)[response.item objectForKey:@"UID_ID"]).s){
                return ITEM_BORROWED;
            }
            else{
                return ITEM_NOT_BORROWED;
            }
        }

    }@catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        [AmazonClientManager wipeCredentialsOnAuthError:exception];
    }
    return NETWORK_ERROR;

}

@end
```

Edit: CPU state

```
Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x200c55c0    r1: 0x432b2b00      r2: 0x00000002      r3: 0x00000020
    r4: 0x00000001    r5: 0x200a2d10      r6: 0x1f5c67f0      r7: 0x2fd95a08
    r8: 0x200a4260    r9: 0x000fc09c     r10: 0x1f5c4c40     r11: 0x200a44e0
    ip: 0x3c33c050    sp: 0x2fd95960      lr: 0x0008928f      pc: 0x3a3c3526
  cpsr: 0x00000030
```

Comment: Don't prefix methods with `get`;  that is reserved for a very specific pattern (pass by reference) and this isn't it.

Comment: ok, your right there. I am used to java programming and using "getters" and "setters". Should avoid using it in objective C

Comment: No worries -- not the source of the issue, but consistency w/underlying APIs is always good.    How do you declare and initialize the various constants (i.e. NETWORK_ERROR, ITEM_BORROWED, etc...)?

Comment: I have another class called Constans.m where I have NSString *const ITEM_BORROWED = @"ITEM_BORROWED";
And then I just use #import "Constants.h" in DynamoDBManager

Comment: That looks OK...   Hrm.   Can you post the registers portion of your crash log?

Comment: Sorry for the noob reply but is that something I get from Apple since I cant replicate the crash?

Comment: @Merdon No, he means CPU registers. Also, post the method that crashes, not the one that calls it, we already know it crashes.

Comment: Thanks, I think I posted the right registers now. Just edited the post. From what I understand from the crashlog it is the method "itemStatus" that crashes. Thats the last method posted, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @bbum sry pasted the wrong register first, apple did send me two crash logs.

Comment: @A-Live, from what I have understood, using "self" inside a class method should work if the method it is refering to also is a class method. But it is ugly coding and I have changed this in the current version I am working with. And the code does compile without any warnings.

Comment: I would suggest you think about what's going on in other threads, and whether another thread might be releasing one of your objects while you're using it.

Comment: The other thing to do is to compile your code for release mode, rather than debug.

Comment: @HotLicks, thanks for the tips, so compiling for AD-HOC is not the same as release, I thought it was just with another code signing?

Comment: Dunno what AD-HOC does by default.  But if you're compiling with a different optimization level than the release level then you'll get different behaviors.

Comment: @HotLicks, that did the trick:) Well, the app crashes, so at least now I can do changes and see what might work, instead of waiting 6 days before getting my application rejected. But I still have to find the bug of course. If I could I would give you thumbs up but haven´t reached rep 15 yet:)

Comment: @Merdon Using `self` in class methods is not only normal, it is standard and desirable.  This is why Objective-C class methods are not static methods;  they can be overridden just like instance methods. Those registers show that an object very high in the heap is being retained.  That shouldn't be an issue (and it shouldn't be writable memory at all).   Huh.  Odd.   Hot Licks' suggestions are where I'd go next, too.

Comment: @bbum, thanks for inte input. Now that I actually can test my app and see what works or not I am more confident of finding the bug.

Comment: @Merdon - Great!  I'm always happy to help crash someone else's app. ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
@catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        [AmazonClientManager wipeCredentialsOnAuthError:exception];
        return NULL;
    }
```

Comment: How is that supposed to help?

Comment: i was assuming NETWORK_ERROR wasn't fully a NSString object, at least not after the compile time. this is the itemStatus = [[DynamoDBManager getItem:itemID] retain] implicit call method, who is responsible for the crash.